# Don’t use that supplement or your stomach will (hurt / be hurt / be harmed / be damaged)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-meaning, word-difference, sentence-choice

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me which one of the following self-made sentences does not sound natural. (To me, the only natural one is the #3 and other sentences do not sound idiomatic and natural. I don't know why! Perhaps because I've heard the #3 many times.)

> 1) Don’t use that supplement or your stomach will be damaged.
>
> 2) Don’t use that supplement or your stomach will be harmed.
>
> 3) Don’t use that supplement or your stomach will hurt.
>
> 4) Don’t use that supplement or your stomach will be hurt.

P.S. please let me know which ones and why do not sound natural in this sense?

Comment: They're all "credible". Usually, ***to harm*** implies *cause damage deliberately*, but in your context it's fine because the harm would be caused by a deliberate act (unwisely taking the supplement). #3 can only means you will experience pain in your stomach (which may or may not result in long-term damage), but #4 could be used to mean your stomach would be permanently damaged (perhaps shortening your life expectancy) even though you might not *feel* the effects at the time (perhaps the symptoms might be "dormant" for years or even decades).

Comment: FumbleFingers is correct (as usual). The simple answer is that 1, 2 & 3 are all OK, while 4 sounds a bit odd.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unfortunately I cannot follow you where you say: "#3 can only means you..."! Could you please explain a bit more about #3?

Comment: *My stomach hurts* actually means ***I** am experiencing feelings of pain originating from my stomach*. But I could feasibly say *My stomach is damaged* in a context where even though I'm not actually feeling any pain, I know that damage has occurred. And even though in that *specific* context we wouldn't normally use ***hurt***, it would still refer to the fact of the stomach being harmed, rather than the pain potentially associated with that harm.

Comment: All of the above comments are good advice.  #4 is grammatically correct, has a legitimate meaning, and would be understood, but "hurt" isn't typically used in this exact way.  "Will be hurt" is often used to mean emotionally.  It is also used as a vague term for serious, unspecified injury.  "If you fight that guy, you will be hurt."  It isn't typically applied to a very specific injury like this.  A term like damaged, harmed, or injured would be more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All four of them are grammatically and semantically valid. All are natural, and all have different meanings or nuance - albeit slightly in some cases.

Let's look at the third first. In that case, we have an *active voice* verb in the final clause, ***to hurt***. It is intransitive, and ***your stomach*** is the subject. When *to hurt* is intransitive, it generally means that the subject is the site of a sensation of pain, or if the subject is a being, that the being experiences pain. So, this says that you will experience pain in your stomach if you use that supplement.

The other three have *your stomach* as the subject of the verb in the final sentence, but always in the *passive voice*. That means they would be the object in the active voice, but without a specified subject. So it is effectively saying that some unspecified *something* will either ***damage***, ***harm***, or ***hurt*** your stomach.

Where anything does any of those things to a living thing, or part of a living thing, or sometimes to any physical object, the meaning overlaps. If something is harmed, it is in some way damaged, and if something is hurt there's arguably a degree of harm. *Hurt* is the weakest, and most informal. *Damage*, to me, gives the strongest sense of real, lasting harm/damage, while *harm* is a little milder. That may vary between dialects, though.

I would say *damage* seems the most natural, if you're intending to give that sense at all.